# Count Waveform Periods and Calculate Frequency

Tags: excel, vba

I have some oscillating time v displacement excel data from an actuator that I need to analyze and my goal is to be able to count the cycles using the amount of times the displacement value crosses 0. Almost like counting the period of a sine wave. The problem I am having is that the frequency of this data changes several times throughout the data set and may not always or ever = 0. I think if I had a way to count the amount of times the displacement value "crossed" zero I could use every 3 of those points to calculate the wave forms cycles and frequency. I have written a lot of simple things in VBA but by no means am I an expert so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way to get it done would be to save compare the sign of the previous value to the current value's sign.

For example, value1 = -0.1236 , value2 = 0.5482. So inbetween those two values, you know it must have crossed 0. You can have the program check each value in the data, count up all the times the sign changes and that should be the number you're looking for.

Example code of how to compare the values:

```
If Current_Value < 0 <> Previous_Value < 0 then Counter = Counter + 1
```